# TypeError: <lambda>() takes no arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

I am a newbie to python programming and am still trying to figure out the use of lambda. Was worrking on some gui program after much googling i figured that i need to use this for buttons to work as i need it to

**THIS WORKS**

```
mtrf = Button(root, text = "OFF",state=DISABLED,command = lambda:b_clicked("mtrf"))
```

but when i do the same for Scale it **does not work**

```
leds = Scale(root,from_=0,to=255, orient=HORIZONTAL,state=DISABLED,variable =num,command =lambda:scale_changed('LED'))
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`Scale` calls the function passed as `command` with one argument, so you have to use it (although throw it away immediately).

Change:

```
command=lambda: scale_changed('LED')
```

to

```
command=lambda x: scale_changed('LED')
```

Comment: `_` is traditionally used as marker of 'unused argument': `command=lambda _: scale_changed('LED')`

Answer (score 5):

This is presumably because the command is passed an argument that perhaps you don't want. Try changing the lambda from

```
command=lambda:scale_changed('LED')
```

to

```
command=lambda x:scale_changed('LED')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should consult Tkinter [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/scale.html):

> Scale widget
>
> `command` - A procedure to be called every time the slider is moved. This procedure will be passed one argument, the new scale value. If the slider is moved rapidly, you may not get a callback for every possible position, but you'll certainly get a callback when it settles.
>
> ---
>
> Button widget
>
> `command` - Function or method to be called when the button is clicked.

Change your `lambda` to

```
command=lambda new_scale_val: scale_changed('LED')
```